# Should I pass CancellationToken to Task.Run() when it is visible from inside of current function

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

Code that test cancellation token I found in book. Just wondering, why `token` is passed as parameter to `Task.Run()`. According to my understanding it is useless. I can omit this parameter and code will run in same way. I'm right?

```
public static void testCancellationToken()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Write("*");
        }

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    },token);

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("press any key to stop task");
        Console.ReadLine();
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got exception "+ e.InnerExceptions[0] );

    }

}
```

Comment: When you pass a CancellationToken as a parameter, it is checked before a new task is scheduled. This way you can cancel a task before it is even created.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not really. In your case, cancellation token is there to signal the `while` loop to stop looping.

Cancellation tokens are meant to be used by other piece of code, that can stop execution of some other thread - for example, you have a long-running cancellable action and you display a dialog window with Cancel button while it is running.

You provide `CancellationToken` to your `async Task` via `cancellationTokenSource` and when user presses the Cancel button, you call `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method, which will cause all tokens associated with this source to flag cancelled state.

If the `async` method is correctly implemented, it will cancel in the first possible moment.

Best practice is to provide `CancellationToken` parameter (even if defaulted) to every cancellable `async` method signature (and, of course, implementation), so the callers can implement cancellation in their code.

Answer (score 2):

> When a task instance observes an `OperationCanceledException` thrown by user code, it compares the exception's token to its associated token (the one that was passed to the API that created the Task). If they are the same and the token's `IsCancellationRequested` property returns true, the task interprets this as acknowledging cancellation and transitions to the Canceled state.

> If the token's `IsCancellationRequested` property returns false or if the exception's token does not match the Task's token, the `OperationCanceledException` is treated like a normal exception, causing the Task to transition to the Faulted state.

Source: [Task cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)

I would expect this information to be in the documentation for `Task.Run()`, but alas could not find it there.

Answer (score 1):

The code may not run in exactly the same way.  If you pass the cancellation token `Task.Run`, the task scheduler will not start your task at all if the cancellation token gets signaled before the task makes it to the thread pool.